# Need a simple python program to convert SRID 102002 (LCC) to WGS84

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, convert, pyproj

I'm going to convert some coordinates from Canada LCC (SRID 102002) into WGS 84 (EPSG/SRID 4326).

I found a Python package for this purpose which is pyproj. However, seems it doesn't support 102002.

since I get this result:

`Proj("+init=EPSG:102002")`

> CRSError: Invalid projection: +init=epsg:102002 +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)

`Transformer.from_crs(102002, 4326)`

> Invalid projection: epsg:102002: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)

I know there is a way to define a new coordinate with pyproj but it needs expertise in GIS which I don't have. [Building a Coordinate Reference System in pyproj](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs.html)

Would you please help me to create that coordinate reference system or give me a simple python code to convert those coordinate to each other?

I found this but it doesn't work fine:

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> p = pyproj.Proj("+proj=lcc +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs")
>>> p(7678236.84856942, 1280719.40571689,inverse=True)
-27.952924124739766 15.502198604012452
```

but I expect a pair of number near (45.4330538,-75.722731)

Comment: that's an ESRI code not an EPSG code

Comment: Does the data provider have a WKT or description of Esri:102002? Lat/lon coordinates are in/near Ottawa. 102002 coordinates for Ottawa are quite different. Statistics Canada LCC (3348) is closer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ESRI:102002` for Canada LCC: https://epsg.io/102002

```py
Transformer.from_crs("ESRI:102002", "EPSG:4326")
```

Comment: which doesn't give the "correct" answer - (72.50527788053216, 70.53351525126045) isn't in Canada for sure!

Comment: Is axis order an issue here?